# Ошибка при использовании [ ( ngModel ) ]

Tags: angular2, angular4, angular5

Всем привет! Начал изучать только Angular и столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Empty expressions are not allowed ("
<app-car></app-car>
<app-car></app-car>
<input type="text" class="form-control" [ [ERROR ->](ngModel) ]="inputText"/>
<p>{{ inputText }}</p>"): ng:///AppModule/CarsComponent.html@5:42
```

Вот код cars.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cars',
  templateUrl: './cars.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cars.component.css']
})
export class CarsComponent {
  addCarStatus = '';
  inputText = '';
  constructor() {}
  addCar() {
    this.addCarStatus = 'Машина добавлена!';
  }
}
```

cars.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addCar()" >Добавит машину</button>
<p>{{ addCarStatus }}</p>
<hr>
<app-car></app-car>
<app-car></app-car>
<input type="text" class="form-control" [ (ngModel) ]="inputText"/>
<p>{{ inputText }}</p>
```

Как я понимаю [ (ngModel) ] создает двойную связь ШАБЛОН <--> КОМПОНЕНТ, но из-за чего возникает ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ! Возможно это кому-то поможет!
Ответ:

Two things you need to do while using two-way binding syntax in forms in RC5.
1) Include FormsModule in your app.module.ts
2) Use name attribute in your html input tags like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="par.name" />
```

That's all.
Ссылка на ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/39025893/8836684

Answer (score 0):

Проверь есть ли у тебя в "app.module.ts"

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CarsComponent,
    CarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, <<<========= Это!!!!
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```